# GitLab CE the issue template does not show

Tags: gitlab

I'm upgrading the `GitLab CE` to version `10.4.1` via the `Docker`. After creating the new project, I pushed the `.gitlab/issue_templates/*.md` and `.gitlab/merge_request_templates/*.md` to the new created repository.

Anyhow when I create new issue, there is no drop-down list displayed for those issue templates. On the other hand the new merge request display its template correctly.

I also try to stop/start docker, sadly the trouble still exist.

Furthermore, the existing projects which are created before this upgrading display both of issue template and merge request template properly.

Could you please help to advise? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Same issue. Found any solution?

Comment: After upgrade to the new version as 10.4.2, the previous project seems to display the issue template properly. I cannot confirm since there is no any new project from my side. I keep monitoring.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I managed to fix the issue by renaming the template file. I used in my case all smallcaps, no spaces. Don’t know if that was really the issue. But now it works.

Comment: You need to have at least two templates for that to work. 
Probably not the solution for you. 
But I wanted to through it out there since that the problem for me when I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add two or more templates inside `.gitlab/issue_templates` directory. If you are using GitHub in the past and you decided to move to GitLab, move `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/*.md` and `.github/MERGE_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/*.md` to the directories that I said earlier. Then confirm if they are working and if not, repeat steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create and push .gitlab directory with .md files on your ***default*** branch.

> As per the official doc [site](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/#default-branch):
> Only the templates of the default branch are taken into account.